# Can dart templating handle recursive mixed structures?

Tags: recursion, dart, dart-webui

I'm entirely new to Dart so excuse my ignorance.

Lets say I was trying to model a tree which had frames and paragraphs. A frame could hold paragraphs, and other frames (recursive). (Note: These frames are not iframes, just a box to hold content really.)

```
Frame
   Paragraph
   Frame
      Paragraph
      Paragraph
      Frame
         Paragraph
    Paragraph
    ...
```

There is no prescribed structure to these trees. Just wondering how one would use dartUI to display a recursive tree structure with mixed types like this. Can you do it via templating/binding?

Edit: This tree structure is dynamic and changed at run time (i.e. users can add frames and paragraphs). So what I'm looking for is a method to generate the view from this model without the calls back to the server to generate new content structures.

I was thinking maybe the `template iterate` could be used to iterate over all the children of a Frame and somehow switch what element is inserted based on whether the child is a paragraph or frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<content>` tag to insert arbitrary HTML into a web component. You can use CSS selectors to restrict the content that appears within the content area. A full implementation of your example of a Frame element that can hold other frames and paragraphs might look something like this:

**x-frame.dart:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <element name="x-frame" constructor="FrameComponent" extends="div">
      <template>
        <content select="div[is=x-frame], p"></content>
      </template>
      <script type="application/dart">
        import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

        class FrameComponent extends WebComponent {
        }
      </script>
    </element>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Using nested frames:**

```html
<x-frame>
  <p>Hello There!</p>
  <x-frame>
    <p>We are nested.</p>
  </x-frame>
  <x-frame>
    <x-frame>
      <p>A third level!</p>
    </x-frame>
  </x-frame>  
</x-frame>
```

You can read the [Dart WebUI article](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/#composition) for more info.

Note: The content select matches against div is attribute since component tags are converted to that format (in other words, even though we can create frame components through `<x-frame>`, they will show up in the DOM as `<div is="x-frame">`

Comment: What's with `content select="div[is=x-frame], p"`? I cannot find this in the (very, very sparse) docs of WebUI.

Comment: @Pixel So using this method something would have to generate the <x-frame><p>Hello There!</p> content - is there another method whereby a tree is modeled (i.e. each object has a parent and a list of children) and you can generate that content dynamically? Was thinking that there might be something like a `template iterate` which could also conditionally switch what is displayed.

Comment: @DrColossos The content tag specifies that HTML can be inserted into the component at that point. Select uses CSS selectors to specify what HTML tags are allowed to be inserted. In my example, only `p` tags and `div` tags with an `is` attribute of `x-frame` can be inserted into the component.

Comment: @gremwell Well, you can combine this method with template iterate and probably achieve what you want.